# Unit Testing - Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have made small test class for my simple application.

I have some problems with `ApplicationContext` and can not autowire some classes.

Here is my test class:

```
package com.myapp.adminpanel.test;


import com.myapp.adminpanel.service.CityService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class CityServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public CityService getCityService() {
            return new CityService();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private CityService cityService;

    @Test
    public void testServicePackage() {
        assertEquals("com.logate.adminpanel.service.CityService",this.cityService. getClass().toString());
    }
}
```

The following code: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Stack trace:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

```
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getCityService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.logate.adminpanel.repository.CityRepository com.logate.adminpanel.service.CityService.cityRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.logate.adminpanel.repository.CityRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
... 29 more
```

Comment: Add the full stacktrace... One thing is make your `ContextConfiguration` class `public` instead of default. And remove the `loader` argument from the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It haven't directed your test to use any configuration. 
Say context configuration what configuration to use :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ContextConfiguration.class)
public class CityServiceTest {
```

It's better to rename your *ContextConfiguration* to something less misleading (MyTestConfig, etc)

Second approach, you can annotate your test as Configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configuration
public class CityServiceTest {


    @Bean
    public CityService getCityService() {
         return new CityService();
    }

}
```

But i see no sense in it, cause your cannot reuse your bean declaration in other test and you can just instantiate object with new :

```
private CityService cityService = new CityService();
```

So the best choice is extract your config to separate class and pass it to *ContextConfiguration* as *classes* argument

Comment: I have created new class in config folder and put `Configuration` anotation in it. Also, I have created method getCityService with `Bean` anotation. Then in my test class I have create anotation `ContextConfiguration`(classes=TestConfig.class) and autowire my CityService object but I have same error.

Comment: please provide stacktrace

Comment: you have to declare CityRepository bean, cause it transitive dependency. You can make it enable to autowiring by adding @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.logate.adminpanel.repository"}) to your test configuration

Comment: just to put @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.logate.adminpanel.repository"}) ?

Comment: yes to your test config. try it. But did you understand a problem? your service class has field that should be autowired, and your context doesn't know about this bean, you have to let your context know how to autowire your repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125883/discussion-between-heril-muratovic-and-sergii-getman).